# Get the blob URL of output file written by sink operation in a Data Flow Activity - Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I have a Data Flow which reads multiple CSV files from Azure Data Lake and writes them into Azure Blob Storage as a single file. I need to get the url of the file written to the blob.
This data flow is a part of a pipeline and I need to give the Blob url as the output of the pipeline. Is there any way achieve this? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> To create a new column name in your data stream that is the source
> file name and path utilize "Column to store file name" field under
> Source transformation --> Source Options.

[Source Options settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ygfxk.png)

[Data Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGAPy.png)

You can also have a parameter inside your data flow to hold file name or file path and add that parameter value as new column using derived column transformation.
**Please Note:** You need supply value in to your data flow parameter from data flow activity.